# Efficient way to maintain local storage and create backup at the network

Tags: c#, winforms, storage

My application loads data based on the filter xml present at local storage folder in the user machine. It also contains user customized filter. So we need to keep the backup of the folder in user allocated folder in netwrok server. Directly accessing files from network results in network latency which affects the application start-up time.

Is there any efficient way that i can achieve both the objective of efficiently loading the file and also maintaining the backup incase the user machine gets formatted?